# SQL: Assistant?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have list of employees and each can optionally have an assistant. All employee's have EmpIDs [including assistants]. The AssistantID is the EmpID of the assistant. I want to query by EmpID and get back their AssistantID. Special note: An ultimate assistant is the person with a NULL for AssistantID. So for example: Susan's assistant is ultimately Fred [Susan -> John -> Mark -> Fred]. Can someone help with the query/sub-query to retrieve this info? [Using standard SQL, eg, no proprietary sql].

eg:

```
EmpID Name AssistantID
=======================
1, Bob, NULL
2, Susan, 3
3, John, 4
4, Mary, 6
5, Bill, NULL
6, Fred, NULL
```

Comment: Your sql-server does not support tsql?

Comment: The standard SQL restriction means you are out of luck for arbitrary depth. AFAIK the standard dictates WITH RECURSIVE rather than WITH.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe RECURSIVE is optional. I'll leave that for you to research. This is what you need anyway https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Comment: tsql is allowed if need [it's going to be SQL Server 2008].

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45e09/1/0

Comment: Then tag it properly

Comment: If it HAS to used TSql OK but no desired.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to retrieve the undermost assistant of the employees.

```
WITH RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT * , EmpID AS TopEmp
    FROM EMPLOYEES c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.* , r.TopEmp
    FROM dbo.EMPLOYEES c
    INNER JOIN RCTE r ON c.EmpID = r.AssistantID
)
select EmployeeName,Assistant from
(
SELECT 
  e.EmpID AS EmployeeId,
  e.Name AS EmployeeName,
  r.Name AS Assistant,
  r.EmpID AS AssistantId
FROM RCTE r
inner join EMPLOYEES e ON r.TopEmp = e.EmpID
where r.AssistantID is null
) Records
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7cd5/15)

Comment: It's close but if I add another record, "Anderson" it doesn't seem to return the correct results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7cd5/4/0. ***NOTE: I've also removed one of the where criteria to give me things like Bob is Bob's assistant. But for Anderson I would want Bob returned.

Comment: I updated the answer. Partition by EmployeeId was not a good idea.